# In the textbox if user enters minus sign in between or anywhere except for first position, it should jump back to front

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

e.g If user enters `25-694` or `2-5694` or `25694-` it should display `-25694`.

Comment: Should this work with numbers only, or are letters / other symbols also allowed? What delimits the input (assuming '/')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```js
function fix(t) {
  if( /-/.test(t.value) ) t.value= '-' + t.value.replace(/-/g,'')
}
```

```html
<textarea oninput="fix(this)"></textarea>
```